# Generics are invariant, but this compiles without error

Tags: java, generics, invariance

I was getting type mismatch errors, until I refactored code to this:

```
    public final Stream<Map.Entry<E, Integer>> orderedStreamOfEntries() {
        return this.m_map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Entry::getValue))
                .map(AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::new);            
    }
```

- The return type is `Stream<Entry<E, Integer>>`
- The type of the stream at the end of this routine is `Stream<SimpleImmutableEntry<E, Integer>>`

The formal type parameter `E` has this definition:

```
<E extends Enum<E> & MyCustomInterface>
```

I don't understand why this appears to be acceptable to the compiler.  Because Java generics are invariant, even though `java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry` implements `java.util.Map.Entry`, I would have said that `Stream<SimpleImmutableEntry<>>` is not a subtype of the return type, `Stream<Entry<>>`.

Comment: what is the definition of `E` from the class definition?

Comment: @ArtB: I've edited the definition into the question

Comment: When in doubt when debugging I recommend breaking each operation on the stream as an assignment to a specific variable. Using an IDE with refactoring support makes this trivial. That'll let you see the types evolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making two mistakes. The first is assuming `SimpleImmutableEntry::new` is a `Function<Entry, SimpleImmutableEntry>`*, when in fact it can be interpreted as a `Function<Entry, Entry>` which *happens to return* a `SimpleImmutableEntry`.

Secondly, look at the signature for [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper)
```

By returning `? extends R`, the method is free to interpret `R` as a *superclass* of the lambdas return type, meaning even a `Function<Entry, SimpleImmutableEntry>` could result in a `Stream<Entry>`, or even `Stream<Object>`.

The actual interpretation depends on the inferred return type, which in your case is `Stream<Entry>`.

<sub>*Raw entry types used for brevity.</sub>

Comment: <<<The first is assuming SimpleImmutableEntry::new is a Function<Entry, SimpleImmutableEntry>*, when in fact it can be interpreted as a Function<Entry, Entry> which happens to return SimpleImmutableEntry.>>>

That seems to be the key,

Comment: @scottb Yes, it's the same thing. The point is that a `Function<Entry, Entry>` may (read: must) return a subclass of `Entry`.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying.  What confuses me is that my IDE shows the return type from the `map()` function as `Stream<SimpleImmutableEntry<>>`.  if this is truly the return type, then it seems that there ought to be an error.

Comment: @scottb Probably just a bug in your IDE. Type inference is notoriously difficult to get right.

Comment: @scottb That's curious because [Java 6's compiler API](http://javabeat.net/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/) was added so that IDEs use the same code as the javac compiler itself. I believe all IDEs but Eclipse made the switch (which IIRC was because they needed to support continuous compilation in the background).

Comment: @shmosel: I agree that the compiler is most likely inferring `Map.Entry<>` as the return type from `? extends R`.  This is a sensible explanation.  Thanks for taking the time to explain.

Comment: @scottb which IDE are you using btw?

Comment: @ArtB: This is NetBeans v. 8.2 that I'm reading the type information from.